# how to check if the currrent date object lies between a startDate and endDate inside a nested Object in mongoose

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have a nested object like this `votingPeriod: {startDate: ISOdate(), endDate: ISOdate()}`. I am using the following query but still I am receiving an empty object from mongo. `const organizations = await this.organizationRepository.find({ votingPeriod: { "endDate": { $gte: new Date()}}});`
I have even tried it with .toISOString() but it's not helping.

Comment: You are looking for a document with an `endDate` larger than now, according to the title, you probably want: `.find({ votingPeriod: { "endDate": { $lte: new Date()}}})`. With `$lte` instead of `$gte`

Comment: Yes I want those records whose votingPeriod.endDate is greater than the current date. Which means the voting is still open.

Comment: In this case, please provide a sample document

Comment: @nimrodserok thanks for reaching out. I solved this problem. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found answer to my own question and it worked out well. I changed my query from this:

`const organizations = await this.organizationRepository.find({ votingPeriod: { "endDate": { $gte: new Date()}}});`

to this:

`const organizations = await this.organizationRepository.find({ 'votingPeriod.endDate': { $gte: new Date()}});`